# Add custom application to existing umbraco website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I want to create a custom application that sits within an existing umbraco website.  The custom application has nothing to do with the website and will have all of it's own functions and views.

I would prefer it to be on the same host web deployed, but if this is not possible I will create a separate app and host it on it's own sub domain.

EDIT:

Okay so after reading this again, I realized this wasn't being phrased very well.

So what I wanted to do, was have an umbraco website, and then build a separate web application and host it as a virtual application within the umbraco website on IIS, the default setup didn't work, so I am assuming umbraco is eating up all of the routes and then not being able to detect it, gives me the page not found error.

I eventually opted for just hosting the application on a sub domain as it's own website in IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a completely separate application that has nothing to do with the Umbraco website and its going to be hosted on a sub domain.

Then why do you need/want it to be connected to your current Umbraco site in anyway.

Just create a new blank MVC project and host it on its own, then point your subdomain to your new app.

If the two applications are loosely related, you could create a new project in your Visual Studio solution it will not effect your current Umbraco installation.

Comment: I actually wanted to host the application as a virtual application, but it didn't work with basic setup, I eventually just decided to go with the sub domain route, that has less issues

Comment: If you do know of a way to get the site as a virtual application up and running that would be good info to have for the future, as I do not always want to host seperate apps on sub domains but rather as virtual applications